# How do I change BoxShadow when tapping on Container in Flutter using Listener class?

Tags: flutter, containers

I have several Containers in my calculator app with box shadow properties to give it a neomorphic look.
But I want to change the BoxShadow or remove it completely when the Container is pressed.

I have used Listener class to do so, by using onPointerUp and onPointerUp properties.
I have attained the neumorphic look but am not able to change its shadow when pressed.

Here is my code:

```
bool buttonPressed =false;//false by default
 // buttonPressed set to false when  button is pressed
 void _onPointerDown(PointerDownEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        buttonPressed = true;
      });
    }
//button pressed is true when button is released
    void _onPointerUp(PointerUpEvent event){
      setState(() {
        buttonPressed = false;
      });
    }

    return Listener(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
         ...
          boxShadow: buttonPressed ? pressedShadow : unPressedShadow
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(widget.buttonText,
            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
              color: buttonColor,
              fontSize: 40.0,

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onPointerDown: _onPointerDown,
      onPointerUp: _onPointerUp,
    );
```

I have done this in a statefulWidget

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Gesturedetector. I hope I can help, im new at programming and had the same problems as you, Example:

bool buttonpressed = false

```
return Listener(
  child: Gesturedetector(onTap: () {
   setState(() {
    buttonpressed = val )}};
```

```
  child: Container
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
         ...
          boxShadow: buttonPressed ? pressedShadow : unPressedShadow
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(widget.buttonText,
            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
              color: buttonColor,
              fontSize: 40.0,

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: If you want to change the value only one time you can use  buttonpressed = true instead of buttonpressed = value